# Statically linking on 32 bit Windows incorrectly adds a leading underscore

Tags: windows, linker, rust

I am trying to build a Rust library which can use the [Opus](https://www.opus-codec.org/) codec. When compiling for `x86_64-pc-windows-msvc` everything works as expected. However when I compile for `i686-pc-windows-msvc` I get errors about unresolved externals. e.g.

> error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _opus_encoder_create

Obviously this is failing because it's looking for the wrong name! There shouldn't be a leading underscore there. My Rust import looks like:

```
extern "C" {
    pub fn opus_encoder_create(fs:i32, chan:i32, app:i32, err:*mut i32) -> *mut OpusEncoder;
}
```

It looks like Rust is automatically inserting the underscore at the start. Running `dumpbin` on both the 32 bit and 64 bit lib files (built in Visual Studio) gets me:

32 bit:

```
> 7202A opus_encoder_create
```

64 bit:

```
> 7202A opus_encoder_create
```

No underscores in sight!

What am I doing wrong? How do I properly import and call these functions from Rust?

Comment: Microsoft's convention for 32-bit x86 is to prefix external C names with an underscore (_) so Rust is correct, your 32-bit libraries aren't. Given the symbols have the same offset in both versions of your libraries it appears that they're both the same and your 32-bit library is actually your 64-bit library.

Comment: The build configuration is: https://i.imgur.com/DGFL1T3.png which presumably means it's building 32 bit libs? I also just rebuilt the opus project and copied the resulting libs into the right place, just to make sure I wasn't using the wrong ones!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Rust build script which imports the dependencies will need some logic to do different work for different platforms. e.g.

```
extern crate target_build_utils;

use target_build_utils::TargetInfo;

fn main() {
    let arch = TargetInfo::new().expect("could not get target info").target_arch();

    match platform {
        "x86" => { /* import 32 bit dependencies */
        "x86_64" => { /* import 64 bit dependencies */
    }
}
```

My original script took the following approach (caution, this does *not work*):

```
fn main() {
    add_deps();
}

#[cfg(target_arch = "x86")]
fn add_deps() {
    /* import 32 bit dependencies */
}

#[cfg(target_arch = "x86_64")]
fn add_deps() {
    /* import 64 bit dependencies */
}
```

However these `cfg` attributes are for the platform the *build script* is building for, not the platform the actual code itself is building for (this is actually fairly obvious in retrospect)!